# Do we ever see the full Promenade directory on screen in Star Trek: Deep Space Nine?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

According to memory-alpha the Deep Space Nine promenade directory of businesses contained a large number of in-jokes and references to other sci-fi shows:

> The directory appeared on the Promenade beginning with Season 2. The DS9 art department incorporated numerous jokes and references in the directory's listings, including "Jupiter Mining Corporation" and "Diva Droid" (both references to Red Dwarf, being the company that operated the ship Red Dwarf and the company that built the service droid Kryten respectively), "Milliways" (The Restaurant at the End of the Universe from The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy), "Spacely Sprockets" (The Jetsons), "Del Floria's Tailor Shop" (The Man from U.N.C.L.E.), and "Chez Zimmerman" (a reference to Herman Zimmerman, the show's production designer and the man responsible for much of the look of the Promenade set).

I was wondering if any of these are ever visible on screen in any episode of Deep Space Nine?

Comment: The closest shot I can remember us ever getting was over Bashir's shoulder early in "The Way of the Warrior", when Odo is disguising himself as the directory panel and emerges from it. The typography, however, is very small, and at 480i resolution, even the supposed English-language text on it might just as well be random squiggles.

Comment: Great question, I just wish I had a better answer than Uncle Mikey but I think he's correct.

Comment: Google is your friend: https://imgur.com/gallery/vWGE8kd

Comment: http://cache4.asset-cache.net/gc/72045324-lighted-spaceship-promenade-directory-is-gettyimages.jpg?v=1&c=IWSAsset&k=2&d=OCUJ5gVf7YdJQI2Xhkc2QB8Ky58ttXq%2fm%2bDbXaTYFWzxvaVsouvXTxRuCv%2bRPW9vx%2b81FU3c7gnUH3THJao5dQ%3d%3d

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. We're shown a (reasonably) clear shot of the promenade directory in the "[Inside DS9 with Mike Okuda](http://www.zippcast.com/video/9e9dddb673a59958256)" featurette on the S5 DVD.

[image]

A *similar* (note, not identical) listing is found in the [DS9 Companion](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671501062)

[image]

and a zoomable version of the whole tablet (in all six languages) is found on the [LCars website](http://www.lcars.org.uk/lcars_a218.htm)

[image]

Comment: What's the going rate for used photons compared to new?

Comment: @JAB - I'll give you two for one. I need to travel light

Comment: OMG, it's Milliways! I never knew Milliways was located on DS9 lol

Answer (score 0):

Let's see how many of these I can annotate from memory.

Diet Smith is the billionaire inventor from the Dick Tracy strip, inventor of the Two-Way Wrist Radio and the Space Coupe.

Yoyodyne Propulsion Systems was the weapons manufacturer that served as a cover for the Red Lectroids in Buckaroo Banzai (See also Banzai Institute)

Cavor's Gravity Devices is a reference to Dr Cavor, inventor of Cavorite in The First Men in the Moon by H. G. Wells

Forbin Project is a reference to Colossus by DF Jones and the movie adaptation Colossus, the Forbin Project

Sirius Cybernetics Corporation - HHGGTG

Tom Servo's used robots is a hat tip to MST3K

The Happy Bottom Riding Club was a dude ranch, restaurant, and hotel operated by aviator Pancho Barnes near Edwards Air Force Base (I looked that one up - I thought it was a Cisco Kid reference at first)

Comment: This answer would make a far better basis for a self-answered new question "What are the various promenade shops named after?". For the record Jupiter Mining Corp is from Red Dwarf.