# What are all the jokes on the DS9 Promenade Directory?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

This image shows all of the shops along the promenade on DS9.

[image] 
<sub><sup>[**LCARS DS9 COMPUTER DISPLAY**](http://www.lcars.org.uk/lcars_a218.htm)</sup></sub>

**What are all the in-jokes and references?**

Comment: Just for reference, not a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108551/do-we-ever-see-the-full-promenade-directory-on-screen-in-star-trek-deep-space-n/109708?noredirect=1#comment494433_109708 which asks if we ever see the directory

Comment: I like the "Milliway's" reference. Oh, crap.  "Spacely Sprockets" does George Jetson work on DS9?

Comment: Jupiter Mining Corporation and Diva Droid Corporation are Red Dwarf references. Spacely Sprockets is from the Jetsons. Tom Servo is from Mystery Science Theatre 3000, although I'm not sure when that originally aired so not sure which show was referencing which. Milliways and Sirius Cybernetics are from Hitchhiker's Guide. I'm sure there are more but that's all the ones I can recognise.

Comment: Yoyodyne Propulsion Systems is from Buckaroo Bansai across the 8th Dimension. It was the front company used by the 8th Dimension aliens.

Comment: while not  a joke persea the idea of "used photons" is so ridiculous as to be laughable

Comment: vinces gym may be a reference to Vince gironda http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Rick_Berman

Comment: BTW I think your question should indicate where the image came from.

Answer (score 73):

1. Amphitheater
2. Andorian Fast Food
3. Bajoran Consulate
4. Bajoran Customs
5. Banzai Institute

   > Reference to [The Adventures of Buckaroo Banzai Across the 8th Dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Buckaroo_Banzai_Across_the_8th_Dimension)
6. Berman’s Dilithium Supply

   > Possible reference to [Rick Berman](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Rick_Berman), executive producer of TNG and co-creator of DS9.
7. Bowling alley

   > Possibly a reference to the [bowling alley](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Bowling_alley) that was supposedly found at the rear of the original Enterprise .
8. Cargo Loading and Transfer
9. Cavor’s Gravity Devices

   > From Dr. Selwyn Cavor the inventor of the antigravity mineral Cavorite from the H. G. Wells book [The First Men in the Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_First_Men_in_the_Moon).
10. Chief Engineers Office
11. Curry’s Martial Arts Training

    > Reference to Deep Space Nine special effects artist [Dan Curry](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Dan_Curry).
12. Del Floria’s Tailor Shop

    > Reference to the [concealed front entrance](https://youtu.be/CjmOkqU6Roo?t=11s) used by the men from U.N.C.L.E.
13. Diet Smith Corporation.

    > [Diet Smith](http://dicktracy.wikia.com/wiki/Diet_Smith) was an inventor (think Q from James Bond) who helped Dick Tracy.
14. Diva Droid Corporation

    > Red Dwarf reference. [Diva Droid International](http://reddwarf.wikia.com/wiki/DivaDroid_International) was the company that built Kryten
15. Dock Master’s Office
16. Federation Consulate
17. Forbin Project

    > Reference to the movie [Colossus: The Forbin Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossus:_The_Forbin_Project) (based on the book *Colossus*, by D.F. Jones).
18. Frederickson’s Squid Vendor

    > Reference to Deep Space Nine scenic artist [Anthony Fredrickson](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Anthony_Fredrickson).
19. Garak’s Clothiers
20. Geological Assay Office
21. Gocke’s House of Mirrors

    > Reference to sound mixer [Bill Gocke](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Bill_Gocke). The mirrors in question may be a reference to his famous gaffe, inadvertently appearing in a [reflection in TNG: Unification](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/8/8e/Bill_Gocke.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/240?cb=20131121234640&path-prefix=en)
22. Klingon Consulate
23. Import Protocol Office
24. Infirmary
25. Jacobson’s Used Photons

    > Reference to lamp operator [Phillip Jacobson](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Phil_Jacobson), primarily responsible for set lighting, hence photons.
26. Jupiter Mining Corporation

    > Red Dwarf Reference. [JMC](http://reddwarf.wikia.com/wiki/Jupiter_Mining_Corporation) was the company that built and ran the titular Red Dwarf
27. Lodging and Accommodations
28. Milliways

    > This is [the "Restaurant At The End Of The Universe"](http://hitchhikers.wikia.com/wiki/Milliways) from the book of the same name, part of the Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy series by Douglas Adams.
29. Pancho’s Happy Bottom Riding Club

    > A real life dude ranch called the [Happy Bottom Riding Club](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_Bottom_Riding_Club) owned and operated by [Pancho Barnes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancho_Barnes) who was also a well know aviator in her own right.
30. Quark’s Bar
31. [Replimat](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Replimat) Cafe
32. Richarz’ Accessories

    > According to Memory Alpha, a reference to the name of the set designer from DS9, [Laura Richarz](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Laura_Richarz).
33. Rush Dilithium Crystals

    > reference to director of photography [Marvin V. Rush](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Marvin_V._Rush).
34. Schoolroom
35. Sirius Cybernetics Corporation.

    > Reference to [Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy](http://hitchhikersguidetoearth.wikia.com/wiki/Sirius_Cybernetics_Corporation). These are the mindless jerks that built Marvin the Paranoid Android.
36. Spacecraft Resupply
37. Spacely Sprockets

    > This is the [corporation](http://thejetsons.wikia.com/wiki/Spacely_Space_Sprockets,_Inc.) that George Jetson works for in The Jetsons.
38. Station Operations
39. Station Security
40. Subspace Communications
41. Tom Servo’s Used Robots

    > [Tom Servo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Servo) is a robot puppet from the show Mystery Science Theatre 3000
42. Vince’s Gym

    > Possible reference to [Vince Gironda](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vince%27s_Gym) by Art Dept person Doug Drexler was a member of the famous real [Vince's Gym](http://www.seeing-stars.com/Play/VincesGym.shtml) for twelve years
43. Vulcan Embassy
44. Yoyodyne Propulsion Systems

    > Probably a reference to Buckaroo Banzai; Yoyodyne was the front organization for the aliens. Yoyodyne was first introduced in novels by [Thomas Pynchon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoyodyne).
45. Chez Zimmerman

    > reference to Deep Space Nine production designer [Herman Zimmerman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herman_F._Zimmerman).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73948/discussion-on-answer-by-broklynite-what-are-all-the-jokes-on-the-ds9-promenade-d).

Comment: Yoyodyne may also be a reference to Rocketdyne https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocketdyne

Comment: I was entirely delighted to see Milliways on this list

Comment: For a station full of uniformed personnel, there sure are a lot of tailors aboard...

Comment: @steenbergh what, you never heard of the Tailor Shops of Isher?

Comment: Panchos Happy Bottom Riding Club was an actual place. It was located near Edwards Air Force Base. It was the favorite hangout and wateringhole for pilots at Edwards. It was open from from the 1930s to the early 60s when it was destroyed in a fire.